# Chrome Extension url extension match '/'

Tags: google-chrome-extension

As per the manifest file code below, I always need to open http://example.com/ for the url to match the pattern. I want the url to be matched even if it is http://example.com (without '/' in the end).

```
"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": [
  "http://example.com/*"
],
"js": ["myscript.js"]}],
```

How do i do this?

Comment: `"http://example.com/*"` *actually matches* `"http://example.com"`. What is the problem?

Comment: No, it isn't working that way. When I explicitly type example.com, it doesn't match. But when I reload the same page, it works

Comment: It should work and it does. Just tried on `example.com` and `www.google.com`.

Comment: Could it be a OS problem? Im using Chrome for Mac.

Comment: Can't say for sure but I doubt it because `domain.com` is equal to `domain.com/` as both have an empty `path` component. Can you upload the entire extension for me to test it here?

Comment: @ArunSethupat your code should work.(at least, above code is fine). Chromium tests include`http://a.com/*`. It should work. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/test/data/extensions/api_test/content_scripts/dont_match_host_permissions/manifest.json&l=15